# Run latest mysqldump from bash script

Tags: bash, mysql

I have a load of mysqldumps like this:

```
dump.data.YYYYMMDD.sql
```

Any ideas how I can run the latest one from bash?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
LATEST=$(ls -1t dump.data.*.sql | head -n 1)
echo $LATEST
```

Note that character in `ls -1t` before the 't' is the digit '1' not the letter 'l'.,

Comment: This will not print the latest. Use `tail` instead.

Comment: The 't' argument to `ls` means sort by time, newest/latest first... this tests correctly for me.

Comment: So that would actually depend from time modified and not by filename? I guess our solutions have different approach. Also you need to use `shopt -s nullglob` to make no matches if no match is found.

Comment: Ah, true, I was testing for the file of a matching name that was generated the most recently, rather than the sort-order of the names.  To trust the naming, `ls -1r` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s nullglob  ## Make no expansion if no file is found from pattern.
if read -r LATEST < <(printf "%s\n" dump.data.*.sql | sort -rn); then
    echo "Processing $LATEST."
    (do something with $LATEST)
fi
```

Comment: Are there any advantages to this than the answer supplied by @Michael - sqlbot? His seems simpler.

Comment: @MrGoobri Since patterns are sorted in bash by the fault, and that it's changed to use tail instead of head, I think there isn't much. But at least you could test that there is a data around without using `[ -n ]`.